# Assigning a field to a model only when it is part of another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning Django, and I've found myself in the following scenario: I have a `project` model with various fields. One of which is `key_personnel`. The other is `key_person_roles`, which defines the roles played by each key personnel on the project.

- A project can have various key personnel, and each key personnel can have various roles.
- Key personnel do not have default roles, they can play any roles on different projects.

How can I best model this scenario in Django? I can't seem to find examples on how to model such a scenario. Here's my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfield import PhoneNumberField


class Key_Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact = PhoneNumberField()        

    class Meta:            
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = "Key Persons"


    def __unicode__(self):            
        return self.name


class Key_Person_Role(models.Model):        
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)        

    class Meta:            
        verbose_name_plural = 'Key Person Roles'        

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.role


class Project(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    # more fields here ...        
    key_persons = models.ManyToManyField(Key_Person)

    # What I want is to assign a role to each key person above.
    key_person_roles = models.ManyToManyField(Key_Person_Role)        

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.title
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a custom [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model/table for the m2m relation between `Person` and `Project` (*refusing to use your mix of camel and snake case). This model can then have a `ForeignKey` to a `Role`. This way, every relation between a person and project is characterized by a (reusable!) role:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ....

# model to capture the different types of roles
class Role(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)     

class Project(models.Model):
    # specify custom through model
    key_persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='ProjectPerson')

# m2m-model for project-person relation
class ProjectPerson(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', ...)     
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', ...)  
    # such a relation has a role!
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role', ...)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('person', 'project'),)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works perfectly! For the admin part, [I found this in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models).

Comment: I had to change from `unique_together(('person', 'project'),)` to `unique_together = (('person', 'project'),)`

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. Corrected!